# Django Celery apply_async doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-celery

we're using django 1.10, Celery 4.1.0

I'm trying to use apply_async.
This is the task:

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('my_app', broker='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/2')


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    print(str(x+y))
    raise status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

When calling it with 'delay' it runs the 'add' function but doesn't retry:

```
add.delay(4, 4)
```

I tried to run the task with 'apply_async' and 'retry'  and 'retry_policy' but it doesn't seem to even run the task:

```
add.apply_async((4, 4),
                        retry=True,
                        retry_policy={
                                      'max_retries': 3,
                                      'interval_start': 0,
                                      'interval_step': 0.2,
                                      'interval_max': 0.2,
                        } 
                )
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is it giving any errors?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev - nothing. I don't see anything in Celery

Answer (score 0):

Check if you've missed the configuration on your **proj/proj/__init__.py** as described in [Celery Docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django)

The file must have:

```python
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Comment: Thanks. It's not that. Actually I resolved that a while ago. Will publish the answer here.

Comment: @user2880391 could you explain how you resolved it ? I am facing the same problem